# Is there a C# equivalent to IsDebuggerPresent()?

Tags: c#

I did find this code snippet, but it doesn't return true when I'm debugging:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
internal static extern bool IsDebuggerPresent();
```

Comment: Only show some buttons when running in the debugger. #if debug would do! In C++ I preferred IsDebuggerPresent because it simply differentiated whether a developer was looking at it or not (in release or debug).

Comment: That's not correct. `#if DEBUG` doesnt' guarantee that you're debugging, it just states that DEBUG is set.

Comment: @Alex That's why it was a comment. As you've stated though it's not a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
```

Comment: Thanks - can't believe I couldn't find this when Googling!! ... hopefully this question and answer will solve that one ;-)

Comment: Glad to help, please mark it as correct so others can find it more easily

Answer (score 7):

You tagged your question as `C#` so I'm assuming when saying "but it doesn't return true when I'm debugging" you actually talking about managed debugging.

The [`IsDebuggerPresent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function checks for a native debugger being present. In your case you should use [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) to check if a (managed) debugger is present.

Also refer to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/07/03/managed-vs-native-apis.aspx) for more information on the debugger APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The member of the .NET Framework that resembles [`IsDebuggerPresent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx) the most is obviously [`Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(v=vs.110).aspx), but their internal workings are entirely different, just like [`Debugger.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.log(v=vs.110).aspx) works very differently from simple [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx).

- `Debugger.IsAttached` asks the CLR for the presence of an attached
  managed debugger, and never even bothers to check for the presence of a
  native debugger.
- `IsDebuggerPresent()` asks the kernel for the presence of an attached native debugger, and has no knowledge of managed debuggers whatsoever.

As of Visual Studio 2013, the managed debugger is built on top of a native debugger, so both `IsDebuggerPresent()` and `Debugger.IsAttached` should return true when debugging a managed application under VS. But if you happen to attach Visual Studio to a managed application and explicitly override the code type to native, `IsDebuggerPresent()` will return true while `Debugger.IsAttached` still returns false.

In the end, it all comes down to what you are trying to achieve.